# Picasso.with() is not retrieving the image in android

Tags: android

```
foodImage=(ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

String url1="https://d9hyo6bif16lx.cloudfront.net/live/img/production/detail/menu/lunch-dinner_soups-salads_crispy-chicken-salad.jpg";
Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(url1).fit().into(foodImage);
```

I am not able to retrieve the image its giving me blank. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: you are using a https url which is not directly supported call by picasso! you have to use okhttp for it! or maybe secure GLIDE lib calls or go for volley or retrofit

Comment: Is there anything in the logs by Picasso?

Comment: I have tried your URL with both Glide and Picasso and its working fine. just check your imageview in xml for dimensions or visibility

Answer (score 0):

Update Picasso dependency to

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

and modify code as -

```
Picasso.get().load(url1).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(foodImage);
```